# I building a Nextjs app, that consume a graphql api from strapi

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, apollo-client, strapi

`next version: 13.3.1`

The point is: using `getServerSideProps` is working but using react `useEffect` don't.

I plan to use `useEffect` to fast update when I create a new post on strapi.

following the Page script:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

// Apollo Client Configuration
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.API_URL,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

// Define your GraphQL query
const GET_JOBS = gql(`
  query Data {
    jobs {
      data {
        attributes {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }`);

export default function Test({ jobs }: any) {
  // const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  console.log("SERVER_SIDE_PROPS >> ", jobs);
  // output with data - working 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchJobs = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await client.query({
          query: GET_JOBS,
        });
        console.log("Jobs:", data.jobs.data);
        // output - TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
        //at fetchJobs (index.tsx:33:17)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    const fetchJobs2 = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await client.query({
          query: GET_JOBS,
        });
        console.log("Complete response:", response);
        // output - Complete response: undefined
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error from server:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchJobs();
    fetchJobs2();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_JOBS,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      jobs: data.jobs.data,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Try to include your question in the title